# iPhone Objective-C cant use 'new' to allocate?

Tags: iphone, arrays, grid

I'm creating a Game of Life program for the iPhone and I want to be able to store previous states of the game in a large array, if I take the C approach and each "Grid" is a structure consisting of two ints for X, Y and a BOOL *array where I malloc the memory proportional to X*Y times the size of the BOOL value I can create 1000 of these 'Grids' at a resolution of 1024x768 in about .014 seconds but when I create an Objective-C type class that replicates this structure it takes .037 seconds. So since I want to speed this up as much as I can but still make the code bearable by adhering to Obj-C as much as possible I ask is there a way to allocate data quicker, I tried new but I can't seem to see why Obj-C doesn't support it!

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand -- perhaps if you posted the code of your two approaches, we could help. Also note: Objective-C does not have "new", which is a keyword in C++. Objective-C is a strict superset of C, not of C++.

Comment: If you need to "rewind" you are probably much better off by only taking a snapshot every `N` rounds and recalculating from there instead of keeping 1000 around.

Comment: There should be a bounty of 100 points, just for the difficulty to read the question. `;-)`

Comment: I don't know if others can see the same AD I see in the right side ("Can't get your grid to work?"). The image of the man pulling his hair seems perfect for this question. `;-)`

Comment: Where does the extra 23 milliseconds make a difference? If you are able to create 1000 grids of BOOL variables at 1024x768 in 37 milliseconds, your users will probably never know the difference. Even if you are displaying those grids at 30 fps, that's over 33 seconds worth of display data, and I'm certain that the computation and rendering code will take *much* more time to run than the memory allocation code.

Answer (score 5):

'new' is C++, not objective C. You can rename your .m files to .mm to have it compiled in objective-C++ mode to support 'new', but if malloc() wasn't fast enough for you, then I doubt new is gonna help you any better.

Comment: uhm, Obj-C has new but for convenience only. it seems that nobody ever uses it:)

Comment: @vodkhang 5ound is referring to the `new` operator/keyword from C++, not to the `+new` method.

Answer (score 2):

Holy run-on question, batman, try using some punctuation and whitespace next time!

First, this `new` thing you speak of is a C++ism.  You can't create an Objective-C instance via the `new` operator.  Go read [this wonderful doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) to gain a deeper understanding of Objective-C.

Now, attempting to parse your question, it sounds like that:

- you have tried creating 1,000 `BOOL *`s by calling `malloc()` 1,000 times?
- ... and you have concluded that the relatively slowness of allocating 1,000 objects is a problem?

There is a more fundamental architectural problem here.  Namely, that you trying to model down to such a fine-grained level with individual allocations, regardless of whether they are `BOOL *`s, Objective-C objects are anything else.

The minimum sized allocation that `malloc()` returns is generally 16 bytes.  That one-bit BOOL (really, it is an 8 bit type;  there are no single bit allocations) is gonna take up 16x more memory than it should.

You are for better off modeling your Grid as a single instance of the Grid class that contains all of the data.  If you need a 10x10 grid with a flag at each point, just `myBools = malloc(sizeof(BOOL) * 10 * 10)`.  Then, any BOOL can be retrieve by `myBools[col + (row * 10)]` -- that is, it is trivial to map a 2D (or 3D) grid of gunk into a linear array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should instead of calling malloc() 1000 times call it once and then set pointers into the memory block. That should be even faster. I don't think though that considering whether new or malloc is faster is the right approach, changing the algorithm usually 10 times more effective.